# How to use ckeditor with coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, ckeditor, railo

I am running railo, and do not have a built in option for ckeditor, and would like to know how to use ckeditor in a webpage. I cannot find any documentation on their website about using with coldfusion.

Comment: Are you trying to do more than just text editing (like file management, etc)? If not, it should just work simply by following the installation instructions and mimicking the demo code. If you want some of the advanced features (like file management, etc) try Googling around, I know others have done that in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The CKEditor Developer's Guide includes an article on [integration with ColdFusion](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ColdFusion/CKEditor_Integration)

Comment: There is no reference to Coldfusion on that link.